# Oracle skipping trailer rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to import the CSV file in the database table by skipping the last rows i.e. trailer rows.
I am using oracle's external table way to import the file. With my knowledge, there is only the way to skip the header in the external table and import. But i want to skip the trailer and import. How can i do it?

Following is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY ext_tab_data AS 'C:\Users\hello\Desktop\';

CREATE TABLE buildinfo_ext (
  "BUILD NO" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_data
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    SKIP 1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      "BUILD NO" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('Info.csv')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Good day!!!!

Comment: What does the trailer record look like? Showing a sample CSV file would be helpful.

Comment: Lets look at the scenario like we dont know the data but now we want to skip the last row no matter how the data look like. But we only know that it is a csv file with some delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This should skip the first row:

```
...
RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
SKIP 1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
...
```

Another approach could be add a field to represent the line number and then use it while querying your table; adding this field should create a field `LINE_NUMBER` containing the number of the row in the file:

```
...
"DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
LINE_NUMBER RECNUM
...
```

In this way you can handle first and last rows the same way, simply checking the row number.

Comment: OP wants trailer records to be excluded.

Comment: This will just skip the header rows. I want to skip the last row.

Comment: By adding a field that contains the row number, you can skip every row you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try thinking of some logic for filtering as below. PS this is not tested code.

```
CREATE TABLE buildinfo_ext (
  "BUILD NO" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_data
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      "BUILD NO" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
    )
   REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS                      ----You can try check if that records is null. Or some other logic,
    (
    "BUILD NO" NUMBER
     TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
     "DATE" DATE
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('Info.csv')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Lets look at the scenario like we dont know the data but now we want to skip the last row

If you don't know anything about the data (e.g. it doesn't have a magic number in the trailer's build number field you can look for; and it won't be rejected anyway because it isn't a number at all; etc.) is with [the `PREPROCESSOR` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1385), having it call a script that strips the last line out of the file for you.

For example, if I create [a simple executable shell script](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#CIHDACJC) called `remove_last_line` (in the same directory, but it can - and should - be somewhere else) containing just a call to `sed` command (or GNU `/usr/bin/head --lines=-1 $1` command would work too on Linux):

```sh
 #!/bin/bash
 /bin/sed '$d' $1
```

then I can tell Oracle that I want the file to be passed through that before it is loaded:

```
CREATE TABLE buildinfo_ext (
  "BUILD NO" NUMBER, 
  "DATE" DATE
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_data
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    SKIP 1
    PREPROCESSOR 'remove_last_line'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      "BUILD NO", 
      "DATE" CHAR(10) DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK "YYYY-MM-DD"
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('Info.csv')
)
--PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

I've disabled the `PARRALEL` option as it clashes with `SKIP`, but you could have your preprocessor remove the header too of course. I've tweaked a few other bits too.

Then I create an `Info.csv` containing:

```
Build number,Date
1,2016-07-01
2,2016-07-02
2 records
```

When I query the table I only see the two valid rows from the file:

```
select * from buildinfo_ext;

  BUILD NO DATE    
---------- ---------
         1 01-JUL-16
         2 02-JUL-16
```

No `.bad` file is produced, and the `.log` file doesn't report any problems:

```
 LOG file opened at 08/09/16 15:56:14

KUP-05004:   Warning: Intra source concurrency disabled because parallel select was not requested.

KUP-05007:   Warning: Intra source concurrency disabled because the preprocessor option is being used.

Field Definitions for table BUILDINFO_EXT
  Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  Data in file has same endianness as the platform
  Rows with all null fields are accepted

  Fields in Data Source:

    BUILD NO                        CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    DATE                            CHAR (10)
      Date datatype DATE, date mask YYYY-MM-DD
      Terminated by ","
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader

Date Cache Statistics for table BUILDINFO_EXT
  Max Size:      1000
  Entries :         2
  Hits    :         0
  Misses  :         0
```

From your directory path you're on Windows, but you can do something similar with a preprocessor batch script. Other operating systems may also need different scripts to achieve the same effect.

Comment: can you please post your shell script called remove_last_line as well

Comment: @Raj_Te - my shell script is a single line, shown in the first code block. It needs to be in a script because I can't call `head` directly with arguments from the `preprocessor` clause. I'll add a shell directive to make it more obvious though.

Comment: The solution looks good but its more about OS oriented. I use KORN shell and its not working in my case.

Comment: It works with ksh too; but yes, this specific example needs a modern GNU `head`; it doesn't work in Solaris 10 for instance, as the built-in head command is different.

Comment: @Raj_Te - changed to use `sed` instead, which works in Linux and Solaris (but may not in other operating systems).

Comment: Mine is IBM - AIX..and its not working however might work for the OP.